# Did I choose the correct statistical test? (Birds pooping on cars)

Tags: chi-squared-test, count-data, contingency-tables

I was asked something like the following on a m/c.

"A researcher comes to you and wants to know whether birds poop more on the roof of cars of a certain colour than others. The researcher gathered a data set on the number of cars observed of a certain colour (red, blue, black, white etc) and whether each car surveyed had poop on their roofs or not, what would you recommend?"

My first instinct was an ANOVA, but it's primarily count data, right?. So I changed my mind to a contingency table + chi-square. Was that the right decision?

Cheers

Comment: I think contingency table + chisq or Fisher's exact is the way to go for simplicity. You could do a logistic glm paired with ANODEV, but like why?

Comment: Contingency was the way to go!

Answer (score 1):

Since each data point (one car) gives an indicator variable (did/didn't have poop), this would be a simple comparison of means of two binomial counts.  The attempt to engage in causal inference, by ascribing different probabilities to the birds, is not justified without some randomisation or other appropriate controls, since there is no reason to expect cars of different colours to have equal exposure to birds.